# Angularjs and Highlightjs - showing variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get Angularjs and Hightlightjs to play nicely with each other and I found this: https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs

This works well enough when displaying static code but when I try to display code using an Angularjs variable it just shows the variable as text.

For example:

```
<div hljs>{{code}}</div>
```

will literally display "{{code}}"

Anyone got any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation for highlight js](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs) you should be using the `source` attribute. That would look like the following:

```
<div hljs source="code"></div>
```

I put together an example for you [in plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5xc93Pib6ubVAbyKZhB8?p=preview) to show this working. Best of luck!

Comment: That's brilliant - I didn't notice that in the docs but I should have done. Thanks